# Como puedo hacer que el programa reconozca que tipo es la variable que el usuario inserta, C++

Tags: c++, variables, scanf

este es el enunciado del problema:
Escriba un programa que le permita reconocer un determinado tipo de dato. El programa debe presentar un menú inicial que permita elegir entre dos opciones:
Datos Numéricos: la operación para esta opción es reconocer si un dato numérico es entero o real
Dato caracter: la operación para esta opción es reconocer si un dato es caracter o una secuencia de caracteres

hasta ahora tengo hecho el menú y estoy intentando hacer que el programa reconozca si el usuario ingreso un entero o un numero real, pero estoy un poco estancado.

```
#include "iostream"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string"
#include "cstdlib"
//system("pause") system("cls");

using namespace std;

//Declaracion de Variables
int seleccion,salida=1;
float d_num,total,res,f;
char c,x;

//Main del Programa
int main(){
    cout << "Validacion de tipos de datos primitivos" << endl;
    while (salida==1){
    cout << "Ingrese una de las siguientes opciones: " << endl;
    menu:cout << "Datos Numericos [1]" << endl;
    cout << "Dato Caracter [2]" << endl;
    cout << "Salir [3]" << endl;
    cin >> seleccion;
    switch (seleccion) {
        default:
            system("cls");
            cout << "Por favor, Ingrese una opcion valida: " << endl;
            goto menu;

            //Datos Numericos

            case 1 :

            cout << "Ingrese un Dato Numerico" << endl;
            scanf ("%f",&f);
            res = f;
            total = res-f;
              if (total >0) {
                system("cls");
                 cout <<("Es un Dato Real.") << endl;
                 system("pause");
                 system("cls");
              }
              else {
                system("cls");
                cout << ("Es un Dato Entero") << endl;
                system("pause");
                system("cls");
              }

            break;

            //Datos Caracter

            case 2 :
            cout << "Ingrese un Dato Caracter" << endl;
            scanf ("%c", &x);



                break;

                //Salida

                case 3 :
                    system("cls");
                    cout << "Que tenga un buen dia. ";
                    salida++;
                    break;
                }
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Lee siempre un `std::string`. En el caso de los numeros, puedes usar `std::find` para ver si tiene un punto, si tiene un punto, es real, si no es un entero. En el de los caracteres, si  `std::string::size` te retorna 1, es un caracter, mas de 1 es una cadena.

Comment: Listo, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Si sobre una variable numérica lees un valor no numérico, el flujo de datos quedará en estado erróneo:

```
float f;

if (std::cin >> f)
    std::cout << "Bien leido!\n";
else
    std::cout << "Mal leido!\n";
```

Si probando el código anterior introduces un texto, mostrará `Mal leido!`.